# Using InteractiveBrowserCredential in DataFactoryManagementClient gives error InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-authentication

I want to start a pipeline run in my Azure Data Factory using python. I have a multi-tenant system, where my Azure account is in one tenant, and the data factory is in the other. I have contributor role to use the data factory and I can use it from the UI.

In python, I use the `DataFactoryManagementClient` to connect to the ADF using `InteractiveBrowserCredential` like in the code below, and I get an error saying:

```
Code: InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant
Message: The access token is from the wrong issuer ...
```

Full code:

```py
credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants='*')
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credential=credential, subscription_id='<subscription-id>')
run_response = adf_client.pipelines.create_run(
    resource_group_name=rg_name, 
    factory_name=adf_name, 
    pipeline_name=pipeline_name, 
    parameters={'counter': '100'})
```

I know that I can create a service principal, give it access to the data factory and use it for creating a pipeline run, but in my org, getting a service principal can take some time because it has to come from the IT.

Can I not use `DataFactoryManagementClient` with a token from a different tenant at all? Is there an alternative to creating a service principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `InteractiveBrowserCredential`, you can specify `tenant_id` in the ctor.

Did you have a chance to try that?

(I am working in Azure SDK team in Microsoft)

Comment: Yes! Specifying the `tenant_id` solved the issue. However, we ended up creating a service principal and accessing those credentials from a key vault since this had to happen on an external device.